# [Unhandled promise rejection: SyntaxError: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 7]

Tags: node.js, react-native

I am just posting user Singup data in my Simple react native app to mongo-atlas. 
Through Postman; same code is working fine and POST user data successfully but through app taking data from user gives the above error. both frontend and backend are runing on separate folders. I think i am not handling the frontend part correctly.

Here is the Front End

```
export default class Formsignup extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      email: '',
      password: '',
      showPass: true,
      press: false,
    };
    this.showPass = this.showPass.bind(this);
  }
  showPass() {
    this.state.press === false
      ? this.setState({showPass: false, press: true})
      : this.setState({showPass: true, press: false});
  }
  getInput(text, field){
    if(field == 'name')
    { 
        this.setState({ name: text, })
    }
    else if(field == 'email')
    {
        this.setState({ email: text, })
    }
    else if(field == 'password')
    {
        this.setState({ password: text, })
    }
  }
  submit(){
    (async () => {
      const rawResponse = await fetch('http://myIpAddress/api/user/register', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          name: this.state.name,
          email: this.state.email,
          password: this.state.password
        })
      });
      const content = await rawResponse.json();

      console.log(content);
    })();
}

  render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <UserInput 
          source={usernameImg}
          placeholder="Username"
          autoCapitalize={'none'}
          returnKeyType={'done'}
          autoCorrect={false}
          onChangeText = {(text) => this.getInput(text, 'name')}
        />
        <UserInput
          source={usernameImg}
          placeholder="Email"
          keyboardType="email-address"
          autoCapitalize={'none'}
          returnKeyType={'done'}
          autoCorrect={false}
          onChangeText= {(text) => this.getInput(text, 'email')}
        />
        <UserInput
          source={passwordImg}
          secureTextEntry={this.state.showPass}
          placeholder="Password"
          returnKeyType={'done'}
          autoCapitalize={'none'}
          autoCorrect={false}
          onChangeText= {(text) => this.getInput(text, 'password')}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress = {()=> this.submit()}><Text>Submit Test</Text> </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is back-end code

```
router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {

    const {error} = registerValidation(req.body);
    if(error) return res.status(400).send(res.send(error.details[0].message));

    //if user already in db
    const emailExist = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email}); 
    if(emailExist) 
        return res.status(400).send('Email Already Exist');

    //hash the password bro 
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);

    //adding new user
    const user = new User({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email, 
        password: hashedPassword 
    });
    try{
        const savedUser = await user.save();
        res.send({user: user._id});
    }catch(err){
        res.status(400).send(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: Please post a screen shot of the error. Very difficult to understand

Comment: print params which you are sending in console.
its 500 error according to me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hie; the way I see it this has something to do with your json response coming from your server side;   here is a tip try :

> res.json instead of res.send for a start

**the code you did for the Fetch function is weak so try this**

```
let data = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      name: this.state.name,
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    }),
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
}
  fetch('http://10.105.4.135:3000/api/user/register', data).then(result=>result.json()) 
  .then((parsedResponse) => {
    console.warn('response',parsedResponse);
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.warn('error', err);
  })
```